# how to start daemon with `--debug-init` or equivalent debugger?

Tags: emacs-daemon, debug

## summary

### problem

I'm trying to debug a problem that involves an Emacs config and daemon startup. But when I run

```
emacs --daemon --debug-init
```

from a console, the spew ends with

```
Loading desktop from /home/me/.emacs.d/personal/ ...
Entering debugger...
```

and hangs until killed. How to make the daemon *properly* enter the `--debug-init` (or other) debugger?

### current workaround

Take [YoungFrog](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/1982/youngfrog)'s [advice](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27376/how-to-start-daemon-with-debug-init-or-equivalent-debugger#comment41833_27376):

`0.` Consider `emacs --daemon --debug-init` to be broken WRT this usecase. (**TODO:** file emacs bug.)

`1.` Start sessions with `emacs --debug-init` (and not `emacs --daemon --debug-init`).

`2.` Debugger will work: use it to resolve all startup problems.

`3.` Once session will load without error with `emacs --debug-init`, return to starting sessions with `emacs --daemon`.

## detour

Another late-night brainfart `:-(` I had tried to run

```
$ emacs --daemon --debug-init
```

(as later [recommended by phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27396/5444)) and got the response

```
emacsclient: unrecognized option '--daemon'
```

Next morning I realized

```
$ alias emacs
alias emacs='emacsclient -c -a emacs'
```

and therefore that I needed to run (in bash)

```
$ \emacs --daemon --debug-init
# ^--note backslash needed to override the alias
```

which works ... except that it gives the problem described in section=`summary`.

## details

### reproduction procedure

I'm running the GNU Emacs 24.4 GUI via daemon on a vanilla Debian stable=Jessie with minor bits of testing (none involving Emacs). I'm rebasing my old'n'crufty, non-package-using emacs config on [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) as follows:

1. Old config (also a git repo, but private) is @ `~/.emacs.d__old_n_crufty/`

2. New config (a Prelude fork) is @ `~/.emacs.d__Prelude/`

3. When I want to check my old functionality, I do

```
pkill emacs                  # ensure daemon not running
rm ~/.emacs.d
ln -sr ~/.emacs.d__old_n_crufty ~/.emacs.d
ls -ald ~/.emacs.d*          # sanity check
\emacs --daemon --debug-init # backslash to override alias
```

4. I copy bits of elisp from my old config to the new, then test latter with

```
pkill emacs
rm ~/.emacs.d
ln -sr ~/.emacs.d__Prelude ~/.emacs.d
ls -ald ~/.emacs.d*
\emacs --daemon --debug-init
```

Just to be excruciatingly clear: both configurations are running the same underlying Emacs version, and both are using daemon+`emacsclient`. The only difference is the configs, i.e., the runtime `~/.emacs.d/`.

Old'n'crufty config works as expected: particularly, the spew in the console in which I run my startup scriptlet ends with

```
Desktop: 1 frame, [much too large number of] buffers restored.
Starting Emacs daemon.
Restarting server
Emacs daemon should have started, trying to connect again
Waiting for Emacs...
```

and then I see my GUI frame. New config was doing fine until I ported my [desktop](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Desktop); now, console spew ends with

```
Loading desktop from /home/me/.emacs.d/personal/ ...
Entering debugger...
```

which hangs until `C-c`. (Note also that both configs are using the exact same desktop file: 2 copies in different filetrees, no symlinks involved (yet, anyway).)

How to make the daemon start/enter the `--debug-init` debugger properly? Alternatively, is there another debugger that plays better with the Emacs daemon, but which does not require major labor?

### workarounds

1. starting without daemon, i.e. just oldschool `emacs --debug-init &`. See this ["answer"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27406/5444), or section=`current workaround` above (to which I'd link but [SE apparently won't support section links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140594/is-there-a-way-to-link-to-a-section-header-in-an-answer#comment397110_140595)).

### failed options

1. `unalias emacs`. I thought, maybe starting the debugger might involve calling `emacs`, and be getting hosed by my alias. Empirically, no change.

### deprecated options

1. Recompiling Emacs with debug symbols. That seems like a *lot* of work.
2. Bisecting config. This is unnecessary, because I've been porting function from old'n'crufty config to Prelude-based config step-by-step, and I know exactly *what* is failing: it's loading my old desktop. What I want to investigate is,

   - exact same Emacs version used for both cases
   - exact same desktop file used for both cases
   - old'n'crufty config can load that desktop with no error
   - Prelude config hangs `entering debugger` with that desktop

Comment: What I do is restart Emacs without --daemon, then debug, and finally restart as --daemon.

Comment: @YoungFrog: Thanks! See [answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27406/5444) (err ... workaround ... but it's all I got right now) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite an answer, but the only currently-working workaround is, take [YoungFrog](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/1982/youngfrog)'s [advice](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27376/how-to-start-daemon-with-debug-init-or-equivalent-debugger#comment41833_27376):

0. Consider `emacs --daemon --debug-init` to be broken WRT this usecase. (**TODO:** file emacs bug.)

1. Start sessions with `emacs --debug-init` (and not `emacs --daemon --debug-init`); debugger will work.

2. Use {"classic" startup, debugger} to resolve all startup problems.

3. Once session will load without error with `emacs --debug-init`, return to starting sessions with `emacs --daemon`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom wrapper script as your `-a` argument value, but you presumably only want to use `--debug-init` temporarily, so... just do that.

Kill your Emacs server if it's running, and then restart it with `--debug-init`.

```
emacs --daemon --debug-init
```

Now connect to it as usual.

---

*edit: TomRoche adds the following...*

Note that, if this throws an immediate error, like

```
emacsclient: unrecognized option '--daemon'
```

you may have aliased `emacs`: check that with (in bash)

```
alias emacs
```

If you have an alias, you can either delete it (with `unalias emacs`) or temporarily override it by preceding the alias with a backslash, e.g.,

```
\emacs --daemon --debug-init
```

Comment: unfortunately, as of Emacs version=24, this fails as discussed in section=problem